# Special Url that React Native can't fetch

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

When I fetch the below url in React Native (0.20.0):

```
http://devshop.aigegou.com/mobile/index.php?client_type=android&act=member_buy&op=buy_step1&ifcart=1&key=fa96e9fe2d84210dd94f28dafb576ac7&cart_id=490|1,491|1,485|1
```

The fetch code:

```
API.prototype.GET = function(url, callback) {
  console.log('GET>>:' + url);
  return fetch(url)
  .then(parseJSON)
  .then((responseData) => {
      if (responseData != null) {
        if (responseData.code != 200) {
          RNManager.showMessage(responseData.message);
          return;
        }
      }
    return callback(responseData);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.warn(error);
  })
  .done();
}
```

it reports:

`(standard input):145715:W/ReactNativeJS(13624): [TypeError: Network request failed]`

But this Url can be loaded in chrome. I think it the format of  **490|1,491|1,485|1** that cause the problem. But how to fix this?

**[Solved]** It's the problem that **fetch()** doesn't do the **URL_ENCODING** for me, so changed the '|' to '%7C'(url_encoded) myself and it worked.

**[Solved Update]** Use `encodeURI()` to do the tricks.